# Nvidia HDMI sound and Logitech Headphones not working in 14.04

Tags: nvidia, sound, 14.04, alsa, hdmi

There is no sound going from the HDMI port on my Nvidia card to my tv that I am using as a monitor. When I use my Logitech Headphones, I hear no sound either. Does anyone know how to rectify the situation? Here's some screenshots and system information (sorry if this is too much info):

- Ubuntu Server 14.04
- Fluxbox WM
- SABERTOOTH 990FX/GEN3 R2.0
- AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
- GeForce GTX 660 Ti (Nvidia 331.20 Drivers)
- Logitech G35 Headphone/Microphone

aplay -L output:

```
default
Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=SB
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
Default Audio Device
front:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
Front speakers
surround40:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Digital
IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=SB,DEV=1
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Digital
Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=SB,DEV=1
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Digital
Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=SB,DEV=1
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Digital
Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=SB,DEV=0
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Analog
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=SB,DEV=1
HDA ATI SB, ALC892 Digital
Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Headset
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Headset,DEV=0
Logitech G35 Headset, USB Audio
Hardware device with all software conversions
```

aplay -l output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Headset [Logitech G35 Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The volumes for the headset look normal, but the volumes for my HDMI output look like this:

[image: AlsaMixer Nvidia Output]

In addition, nothing shows up in the HDMI tab in gnome-alsamixer

[image: Gnome AlsaMixer]